# Python unittest and test discovery

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

What *exactly* I need to do to make python's `unittest` work? I checked the official documentation, SO questions and even tried using `nose`, but nothing worked so far. What I'm doing wrong?

```
bash:~/path/to/project/src/tests$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 342 Out 11 11:51 echo_test.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  71 Out 11 11:28 __init__.py
bash:~/path/to/project/src/tests$ python -m unittest -v echo_test

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
bash:~/path/to/project/src/tests$ python -m unittest discover

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
bash:~/path/to/project/src/tests$ cat echo_test.py
import unittest

class EchoTest(unittest.TestCase):  
    def fooTest(self):
        self.assertTrue(1==1)

    def barTest(self):
        self.assertTrue(1==2)

#suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestEcho)
#unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

As you can see, the tests simply aren't run and I have no idea why(since I'm not a python programmer).
Just for information, I'm using python 2.7 and the `__init__.py` is an empty file.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to rename the methods to begin with the word "test".

As seen on http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html :

> A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about which methods represent tests.

Answer (score 18):

I would like to mention that you **CANNOT** run a python unit test as though it were an executable python file. For example, this was my problem:

```
python -m unittest ./TestMyPythonModule.py

... (stack trace) ...
ValueError: Empty module name
```

It fails.

However, this works:

```
python -m unittest TestMyPythonModule
```

It's easy to overlook at first.

Comment: just to add my cents here. if the test module `TestMyPythonModule.py`resides in the folder `tests`, the correct command is `python -m unittest tests.TestMyPythonModule`. Sometimes the integrated terminals in IDEs autocomplete it like `python -m unittest .\tests\TestMyPythonModule`, but this gives an `Empty module name` error.

Answer (score 3):

unittest.main() will run all the function that begin by "test". So you should rename your functions

```
class EchoTest(unittest.TestCase):  
    def testfoo(self):
        self.assertTrue(1==1)

    def testbar(self):
        self.assertTrue(1==2)
```

Comment: This worked for me. One other thing I had to do to get discovery working (instead of calling unittest.main()) was to rename the file from name_test.py to test_name.py

Answer (score 0):

Test functions must start with the name `test`  So `fooTest` should be `testFoo`.  See the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html)

Also, there isn't a need for the `__init__.py` file, assuming those are the only two files in your `tests` directory.