# How to resolve "ValueError: Empty module name"?

Tags: python, python-unittest

In my `UnitTest` directory, I have two files, `mymath.py` and `test_mymath.py`.

`mymath.py` file:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b

def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b

def divide(numerator, denominator):
    return float(numerator) / denominator
```

And the `test_mymath.py` file is:

```
import mymath
import unittest

class TestAdd(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    Test the add function from the mymath library
    """

    def test_add_integer(self):
        """
        Test that the addition of two integers returns the correct total
        """
        result = mymath.add(1, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, 3)

    def test_add_floats(self):
        """
        Test that the addition of two integers returns the correct total
        """
        result = mymath.add(10.5, 2)
        self.assertEqual(result, 12.5)

    def test_add_strings(self):
        """
        Test that the addition of two strings returns the two strings as one
        concatenated string
        """
        result = mymath.add('abc', 'def')
        self.assertEqual(result, 'abcdef')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the command

`python .\test_mymath.py`

I got the results

> Ran 3 tests in 0.000s
>
> OK

But when I tried to run the test using

`python -m unittest .\test_mymath.py`

I got the error

> ValueError: Empty module name

Traceback:
[image: Full Traceback]

Folder Structure:
[image]

I am following this [article](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/07/07/python-3-testing-an-intro-to-unittest/)

My python version is `Python 3.6.6` and I am using windows 10 in the local machine.

Comment: Please run like this: `python -m unittest test_mymath`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python unittest and test discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728371/python-unittest-and-test-discovery)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `python -m unittest test_mymath`

Comment: According to the [Python 3.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface), what @shams-nahid tried to do is valid: "Test modules can be specified by file path as well: `python -m unittest tests/test_something.py`".  So is this a bug in Python, or is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: Try to add (empty) __init__.py to folder with the test. Even though it shouldn't be needed in python3.3+, it still is needed in python3.7+ for me...

Comment: NOTE: removing **only** the `./` (and not the full path) also works when the test is in a subfolder. e.g. `python -m unittest ./tests/test_something.py` does **not** work while  `python -m unittest tests/test_something.py` **does** work.

Answer (score 17):

You almost got it.  Instead of:

```
python -m unittest ./test_mymath.py
```

don't add the `./` so you now have:

```
python -m unittest test_mymath.py
```

Your unit tests should now run.

Comment: I'm running into this error on github actions, where I need to be able to include the `./` as part of the path. Is there another workaround?

Comment: @szeitlin Can you quote the exact error you are getting?

Comment: ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_gopher_changes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.10/x64/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/runner/work/data-lake/data-lake/automated/gopher_changes/test_gopher_changes.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gopher_changes import Updater
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gopher_changes'

Comment: FWIW I worked around this by changing into the directory where the tests live and running with `python -m unittest discover`

Comment: Windows powershell (for some reason) adds leading ./ after pressing `Tab`

Comment: Oh *god* - worked for me.  Why does this solve the problem?